# RecyclerView grid with different item sizes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I need to create a horizontal scrolling grid that can allocate items with different width and different height. `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` can handle different width but it won't let me have items with different height. Is there any `LayoutManager` implementation which can do what I need?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there's no LayoutManager for that yet. You'll have to implement you own LayoutManager from scratch. The currently available LayoutManagers (as of december 2014) are:

1. LinearLayoutManager
2. GridLayoutManager
3. StaggeredGridLayoutManager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html

**EDIT**:

You can also look at [this](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) if you want to implement your LayoutManager in an easier way...

Comment: I need to implement this kind of logic also. Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier there isn't LayoutManager with such functionality.
You can use GridLayout, or create own LayoutManager.
My answer can be helpful to find out how to lay out items with different size:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36110913/4288054